# Password Hashing in Node.js

Tags: node.js

This is my current code for password hashing and saving to the database:

```
var config = {
  hashBytes: 64,
  saltBytes: 64,
  iterations: 8000
};

crypto.randomBytes(config.saltBytes, function(err, salt) {

  crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, config.iterations, config.hashBytes,
      function(err, hash) {

          var combined = new Buffer(hash.length + salt.length + 8);

          combined.writeUInt32BE(salt.length, 0, true);
          combined.writeUInt32BE(config.iterations, 4, true);
          salt.copy(combined, 8);
          hash.copy(combined, salt.length + 8);

          callback(combined);
      });
  });
```

The goal of the code was to save salt together with the hash to one field in database. Is this acceptable way to store a password/salt in the same field in the database? I've found this algorithm long time ago and now so I'm not sure do I understand this well.

As I understand, first we create a buffer which has enough space to store hash, salt, number of iterations and salt length (not sure why are we adding 8 here):

```
var combined = new Buffer(hash.length + salt.length + 8);
```

Then we save salt length byte to position 0:

```
combined.writeUInt32BE(salt.length, 0, true);
```

We save iterations position 4 (why 4?):

```
combined.writeUInt32BE(config.iterations, 4, true);
```

We save salt to position 8:

```
salt.copy(combined, 8);
```

We save hash to position which is the length of salt plus the size where we saved iterations and salt length:

```
hash.copy(combined, salt.length + 8);
```

Comment: Not an expert in the password encryption field. Have you explored the possibility of using other people's encryption library rather than writing your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems to be making the now-dangerous assumption that "an integer is 4 bytes long, therefore two integers are 8 bytes."

In today's 64-bit world, that assumption would no longer be true.  And, in any case, we don't *need* this level of complexity and byte-twiddling!

A far better *(and, far simpler)* strategy ... *(source-code example not shown)* ... is to simply store all three values as strings, separated by a known character.  For instance, `12:34:5678` being used to store a salt-length of 12, iterations 34, hash-value 5678.  The code that stores the value simply concatenates the three *strings* and stores them in a `VARCHAR` field of sufficient size. And, in like manner, the code that retrieves and checks the value first "splits" the string into its three constituent parts *(e.g.* using a regex ...), converts the first two strings to integers, and proceeds to evaluate.

This is preferable for a great many reasons, not the least of which is that a human being, querying the database, can plainly *see* the three parts. (So, if there's a bug in the code somewhere, s/he can *see* the consequences of the bug "at a glance.")

Comment: I agree and would add a version indicator as the first item particularly as there are different versions of PBKDF2 that use different hash functions and future-proofing seems like a good thing..

Comment: Seems good.  (In fact, "excellent advice."  Database-entries last forever, and, *(these days, thank god ...)* storage is cheap. You've got enough room to make your records "self-describing."

Comment: Thanks @MikeRobinson, would you advise me to also store salt as a part of that entry something like this: `salt_length:salt_value:iterations:hash`?

Comment: The salt-value is customarily stored as part of the string, much as you have shown.  In character form, separated by a character that you can easily `split()` by.  I'm not sure you need `salt_length` since you have the `salt_value` right there.  But, in any case, one thing I'd add, at the front, is a fixed number ... an `algorithm` number, if you will ... that simply identifies (for all time) the method in which this hash was computed.  If or some successor does something different later, all you do is to update that code.  Each hash-string "self-identifies" how it was made.

Answer (score 9):

using library [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) its easy to generate password hash.

#### install & Include

```
npm install --save bcrypt
```

then include the library

```
const bcrypt = require( 'bcrypt' );
```

#### Generate & Verify Hash

to generate hash in Asynchronous way use the following method.

```
bcrypt.hash( 'passwordToHash', 10, function( err, hash ) {
  // Store hash in database
});
```

`10` is the number of rounds to use when generating a salt.
to verify password

```
bcrypt.compare( 'passwordToCompare', hash, function( err, res ) {
  if( res ) {
   // Password matched
  } else {
   // Password didn't match
  } 
});
```

#### Generate & Verify Hash

to generate and verify hash in synchronous way use the following method.

```
let hash = bcrypt.hashSync( 'passwordToHash', 10 );
```

`10` is the number of rounds to use when generating a salt. To verify hash

```
if( bcrypt.compareSync( 'passwordToCompare', hash ) ) {
   // Password matched
} else {
   // Password didn't match
}
```